# Using regression for pairwise choice

Tags: regression, classification, paired-comparisons

I have pairs of objects, in which one is real and one is an artifact, and I need to choose the real one.  Call them $G_\text{real}$ and $G_\text{fake}$.

I compute a score for each object, and choose the one with the greater score

$$\text{total score} = w_1G[1] + w_2G[2] + w_3G[3]$$

where $w_i$ is weight for $G[i]$ = score of item $G$ along dimension $i$. So I would like to set the weights by finding a hyperplane with normal vector $N$ such that the number of cases where

projection of $G_\text{real}$ on $N$ (originating from the origin) $\gt$ projection of $G_\text{fake}$ on $N$

is maximized. Can I use linear regression to do this? I would be satisfied to use regression to minimize

Eq. 2: (projection of $G_\text{fake}$ on $N$ - projection of $G_\text{real}$ on $N$)

but regression naturally minimizes something of the form

$$(A - B) ^ 2$$

which would be completely wrong for me, since in Eq. 2 positive values are bad while negative values are good. I used regression to fit

$\sum_i w_i (log(G_\text{real}[i]) - log(G_\text{fake}[i])) - 1$

This gives an answer that is pretty good, better than LDA, but I am suspicious of it, because it seems dimensions that reliably give large differences between real and fake (which is good) would be penalized.  Some errors would be made by adjusting the weights to make the difference between real and fake /smaller/. The most-informative dimension gets a low weight, possibly because it makes the difference between $G_\text{real}$ and $G_\text{fake}$ "too" large in the eyes of the regression. So I'm throwing out training cases where the score difference is very large; it will get those right anyway. That makes it more like a margin-maximizing classifier

What is important is not the raw score produced for any one item, but the difference between the two items in a pair. For kinda complex & irrelevant biological reasons, the "fake" item in a pair can look very, very much like the real items--the fake item acquires properties from the nearby real item; the scores within a pair are correlated. So trying to train the weights to give the fake ones low raw scores, and the real ones high raw scores, may not work.

So I'm not trying to draw a hyperplane between two classes--I'm trying to find the hyperplane through the origin that has the most "delta" points on one side of it, where each "delta" point is the point for the real item minus the point for the right item. You can see how linear regression could work to find that hyperplane, but it isn't optimal. Using a constant in the linear regression results in offsetting it from the origin and finding a hyperplane thru the middle of this delta data that minimizes least-square distance from the hyperplane; shifting that plane to the origin gives the decision surface. Works pretty well. Don't know what would happen if I did thru-the-origin regression.

I tried this strange linear regression approach, linear discriminant analysis, and random weights from 0-1. The regression, tested on held-out data, performs better than 90% of random weight settings, while LDA performs better than half of them.

Comment: I believe you are unnecessarily narrowing the scope of your question. Why not instead ask *how* to solve your problem rather than asking whether linear regression will solve it?  That will open up the thread to all kinds of classifiers, such as [tag:SVM], [tag:random-forest], etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do regression with 0-1 (or, in your case, 'fake'-'real') valued data, you should try logistic regression. Linear regression usually doesn't work very well on 0-1 valued data.

Comment: The weights don't generate 0-1 values. I convert the scores to a probability using a logistic function, but the important thing is the /difference/ between the raw scores on the good and bad items in a pair.  See additions to the question above.

Comment: How would you use logistic regression on this? I think logistic regression is just a way to reach inside the data to before the logistic function was applied, so that your results get scaled to be within [0 .. 1]. I already have the scores before applying the logistic function, so why would I use logistic regression?  (score is in log(odds), probability = odds / (1 + odds) = 1 / (1 + 1/exp(log(odds))), so my conversion from score to probability is exactly the logistic function.)

Answer (score 0):

Follow Stefan's suggestion, you can formulate this as logistic regression in the following way.

For each pair, consider it as a Bernoulli random variable where 1 corresponds
with the left object being real, and 0 corresponds with the left object being fake.

Then, each pair, a feature vector you could use could simply be the features of the left object concatenated with the features of the right object.

You can then easily augment/constrain your feature vector by taking differences of features between the LHS and RHS object, for instance.